# Hide/Show next Select-statement when an Option is Picked in my first Select-statement

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, show-hide, cascadingdropdown

I'm currently trying to hide the subcategory-select-statement for aslong as there is no maincategory picked in my first select-statement. The same counts for the select-type-statement within the subcategory. The method for a cascading dropdown I use is the same you can find on w3schools, otherwise the code is down below.

Do you know how i can hide the subcategory/type while the select-hierarchy above isn't selected?

For example:

Choose Maincategory(default is "Select Category)", when I change "Select Category" to "MainCategory1" then the select statement of the subcategory appears. Then when the Subcategory option is picked, the typecategory select statement appears.

I hope it is clear what I want to do. Furthermore please excuse my bad use of english. English is not my mother tongue.

```js
var maincatObject = {
  "MainCategory1": {
    "Subcategory 1.1": ["Type 1.1.1", "Type 1.1.2"],
    "Subcategory 1.2": ["Type 1.2.1", "Type 1.2.2"],
    "Subcategory 1.3": ["Type 1.3.1", "Type 1.3.2"],
    "Subcategory 1.4": ["Type 1.4.1", "Type 1.4.2"]
  },
  "MainCategory2": {
    "Subcategory 2.1": ["Type 2.1.1", "Type 2.1.2"],
    "Subcategory 2.2": ["Type 2.2.1", "Type 2.2.2"],
    "Subcategory 2.3": ["Type 2.3.1", "Type 2.3.2"],
    "Subcategory 2.4": ["Type 2.4.1", "Type 2.4.2"]
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  var maincatSel = document.getElementById("maincat");
  var subcatSel = document.getElementById("subcat");
  var typedevSel = document.getElementById("typedev");
  for (var x in maincatObject) {
    maincatSel.options[maincatSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  maincatSel.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
    typedevSel.length = 1;
    subcatSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var y in maincatObject[this.value]) {
      subcatSel.options[subcatSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
    }
  }
  subcatSel.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters dropdown
    typedevSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    var z = maincatObject[maincatSel.value][this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      typedevSel.options[typedevSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="maincat" id="maincat">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Category</option>
</select>
<br><br> Sub-Category:
<select name="subcat" id="subcat">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please select sub-category first</option>
</select>
<br><br> Type/Device:
<select name="typedev" id="typedev">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please select type or device</option>
</select>
<br><br>
```

Solution:

I managed to do it, for those of you who wonder how I did it... here's the modified JS code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var maincatSel = document.getElementById("maincat");
  var subcatSel = document.getElementById("subcat");
  var typedevSel = document.getElementById("typedev");
  for (var x in maincatObject) {
    maincatSel.options[maincatSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
    subcatSel.style.display = 'none';
    typedevSel.style.display = 'none';
  }
  maincatSel.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
    subcatSel.style.display = 'block';
    typedevSel.style.display = 'none';
    subcatSel.length = 1;
    typedevSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var y in maincatObject[this.value]) {
      subcatSel.options[subcatSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
    }
  }
  subcatSel.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters dropdown
    typedevSel.style.display = 'block';
    typedevSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    var z = maincatObject[maincatSel.value][this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      typedevSel.options[typedevSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

The trick was simply to place "variablename.style.display = 'none'/'block';" on the right position. Keep in mind that the code reads from above and for the rest I just used my brain, hehe. I hope this will help anyone who searches for answeres. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<style>
    #sub1, #type1{
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<select name="main" id="main">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Option</option>
    <option value="value1">value1</option>
    <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>
<select name="sub1" id="sub1">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Option</option>
    <option value="value1">value1</option>
    <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>
<select name="type1" id="type1">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Option</option>
    <option value="value1">value1</option>
    <option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>

<script>
    var main = document.getElementById('main');
    var sub1 = document.getElementById('sub1');
    var type1 = document.getElementById('type1');
    
    main.addEventListener('change', function(element){
        if(element.target.value == 'value1'){
            sub1.style.display = 'block';
        }else{
            sub1.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
    
    sub1.addEventListener('change', function(element){
        if(element.target.value == 'value1'){
            type1.style.display = 'block';
        }else{
            type1.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The problem I see here is, that it will do the thing i wanted, but does not work with my cascading dropdown. Because there are no valuesprovided, unless the submit button is pressed. Atleast that's how I understand the w3schools code.  :'D